# Как найти суму всех элементов массива?

Tags: java, массивы

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TwoDArrayDz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 5, n = 5;
        int Array[][] = new int [m] [n];
        Random generator = new Random();
        int gn;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                gn = generator.nextInt(100);
                Array [i] [j] = gn;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.println ("Masiv [" + i + "] [" + j + "] =" + Array [i] [j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            int sum = 0;
            for (int s = 0; s < Array.length; s++){
            sum = sum + Array [i] [j];
            }
            System.out.println("Сума = " + sum);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        sum += Array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В Java 8 можно так:

1. `int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum();`
2. `int sum = IntStream.of(arr).sum();`